# MYSQL: joining 2 sub select query

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I keep getting operand should contain 1 columns error. I thought it may be because the parenthesis but i couldn't figure out what is wrong. 
The first table is to select row with unique pair of (PGF, name), the second table is to select people that work in department that have 2 or more people.

```
SELECT SUM(Salary) FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM Company GROUP BY (PGF, name) HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) as second
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM Company GROUP BY department HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) as first
    ON second.ID = first.ID
```

**Update**: I solved the column error by removing the parenthesis around (PFG, name). However, now I got wrong result from the second subquery and an ambiguous error with the main query. Details below:

[Run second subquery separately - Wrong result returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RavBf.png)

For the second query I wanted to return the people that works in department that have more than 1 people (everyone that share the same department with at least another person). So it should return everyone except Trump, but query only returned 3 rows.

I also tried to run everything together and got this error:  Column 'salary' in field list is ambiguous

Please kindly advise. Thank you!

Comment: Please run the inner pair of selects and post the result. My guess is that you are getting several fields (perhaps including `Salary`) and summing Salary without specifying what to do with the other fields. `SUM` is an aggregative modifier which in some cases is accompanied by `GROUP BY`.

Comment: link to image of orig test database: https://postimg.org/image/pbno5kc29/

Comment: You are right a group by cannot have parenthesis around (PFG, name).The second sub query correctly returns 1 row per company and the ambiguity on salary needs to be resolved by qualifying salary with the sub query alias that you want salary from. Fixing the errors may not give the answer that you want - in fact I'm not clear what you want - if you show the results that you do want that would help.

Comment: From the original database, I would want it to return the sum of the salary of the people with id 1,2,4,5,7,9.